# SharedPreferences.Editor not being updated after initial commit

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I'ma a bit confused here. I'm trying to change the value of an EditTextPreference, but it is not updated in the view. (This is in a PreferenceActivity)

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.modify_instrument_preferences);

  // Set default values
  SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
  modifying = getObjectWithName(); //Some object with a name;

  editor.putString("namePref", modifying.getName());
  editor.commit();
  android.util.Log.d("TEST", "written: "+customSharedPreference.getString("namePref",""));
}
```

My printlns print out valid information, and the commit() returns true, but on clicking the EditTextPreference, it displays the old value. If I rotate the screen, causing the onCreate to get run again, the EditTextPreference has the right value.

So perplexing. Why isn't this change being updated in the UI?

Edit:

I'm not sure why the above isn't working, but I managed to change it just by doing:

```
  EditTextPreference namePref = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("namePref");
  namePref.setText("the text");
```

That updated the view everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I know there are some constructs in place for PreferenceActivities to keep track of this info themselves, it doesn't seem to be well documented. I have found that adding an `onPreferenceChangeListener` to the preference will allow you to make those edits as soon as the preference is changed.