# How to refresh SharedPreferences in android when restore from a file?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I backup the SharedPreferences xml file to the SD card, from the file

```
File taskExceptionFile = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                + "/data/" + packageName + "/shared_prefs/" + TaskAction.SHARED_PREF_TITLE_TASK_EXCEPTION + ".xml");
```

however, when I restore the file, if the file has been open by

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(TaskAction.SHARED_PREF_TITLE_TASK_EXCEPTION, 0);
```

before restoring, the SharedPreferences seems to have a cache, I use Root Explorer to see the file after restoring, the values are indeed the values from the backup file, but when I use

```
sp.getInt(TaskAction.SHARED_PREF_TASK, 0)
```

to get the value, the value is not the new value from the backup file, it returns the default value 0. I force stop my app, and reenter my app, the values are the new values.

So, I want to ask how to refresh the SharedPreferences immediately when I restore the file, so that I can get the new value?

Sorry for my poor English~~~

Comment: Are you calling the SharedPreferences from a thread?  I came across this problem once.  Check my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630926/sharedprefences-not-being-updated

Comment: Why do you save preferences to file on SD card, when actually they are normally stored in more secure location in inner phone's memory?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @DeeV. I tried your answer, and the problem is solved. [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12644472/1393699)

Comment: In my app, I save some settings in the preferences, and the users want to backup their settings without the network, so I backup the preferences and databases on SD card. @squixy

Comment: Hello did you get the solution. I am stuck with same problem. Please help