# SharedPreferences does not update data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have Activity and service.

Activity store and update data into shared preferences file. I was update the data from Activity and then Service try to retrive changes, but he read the old values.

Code :

**Saving\Updating :**

```
@Override
public void save(VolumeBotSettings settings) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
    edit.putInt(START_HOURS, settings.getStartHours());
    edit.putInt(START_MINUTES, settings.getStartMinutes());
    edit.putInt(END_HOURS, settings.getEndHours());
    edit.putInt(END_MINUTES, settings.getEndMinutes());

    edit.putInt(RING_VOLUME_LEVEL, settings.getRingVolumeLevel());
    edit.putInt(MUSIC_VOLUME_LEVEL, settings.getMusicVolumeLevel());
    edit.putInt(NOTIFICATION_VOLUME_LEVEL, settings.getNotificationVolumeLevel());
    edit.putInt(ALARM_VOLUME_LEVEL, settings.getAlarmVolumeLevel());
    edit.commit();
}
```

**Read :**

```
@Override
public VolumeBotSettings retrieve() {
    VolumeBotSettings settings = new VolumeBotSettings();
    settings.setStartHours(sharedPreferences.getInt(START_HOURS, UNDEFINED));
    settings.setEndHours(sharedPreferences.getInt(END_HOURS, UNDEFINED));
    settings.setStartMinutes(sharedPreferences.getInt(START_MINUTES, UNDEFINED));
    settings.setEndMinutes(sharedPreferences.getInt(END_MINUTES, UNDEFINED));

    settings.setRingVolumeLevel(sharedPreferences.getInt(RING_VOLUME_LEVEL, UNDEFINED));
    settings.setMusicVolumeLevel(sharedPreferences.getInt(MUSIC_VOLUME_LEVEL, UNDEFINED));
    settings.setNotificationVolumeLevel(sharedPreferences.getInt(NOTIFICATION_VOLUME_LEVEL, UNDEFINED));
    settings.setAlarmVolumeLevel(sharedPreferences.getInt(ALARM_VOLUME_LEVEL, UNDEFINED));

    if (settings.isNotNull())
        return settings;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Also i re-init shared preferences before using them.

```
private static final String VOLUME_BOT_PREFERENCES = "volume_bot_preferences";

public void init(Context context) {
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(VOLUME_BOT_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

so the step-by-step actions :

```
Activity call init() method.
Activity call save() method.
Close Activity. Service is running.
Service call init() method.
Service call retrive() method.
```

And no data was updated. Please help me to understand why.

---

> **Note.** *init(),save(),retrieve() - methods of Singletone class that located in the same app.
> Retrived **settings** is not null.*

Comment: Are you using same `sharedPreferences` to save and retrieve data?

Comment: @Aashish i hope yes. `VOLUME_BOT_PREFERENCES` is a constant value. It defines sp filename.

Comment: Is the service running on a separate process?

Comment: When you set up the SharedPreference, you need to use `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630926/sharedprefences-not-being-updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem long ago from this question:

[SharedPreferences does not update data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898424/sharedpreferences-does-not-update-data)

Final answer was that since it was across two separate processes, you have to set the flag `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`.  SharedPreferences cache mappings in memory local to your app, so by default the memory isn't shared among processes.  This was implemented in 2.3. I do not believe you can use this approach if supporting less than that.

Comment: MODE_MULTI_PROCESS is deprecated since API 23.

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
public void init(Context context)
{
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(VOLUME_BOT_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
}
```

About this flag :

> when set, the file on disk will be checked for modification even if the shared preferences instance is already loaded in this process.

Comment: Sorry,but the @DeeV answered firstly in comment. I for the honesty) Nothing Personal)

Comment: Not a problem, i did not see his comment ;)